# VueJS 2.0: Deploying to sub-folder comes out blank?

Tags: web-applications, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have been trying to deploy my Vue2 web app into a sub-folder in my domain, but it comes out blank. I've tried several different fixes such as changing the config/index.js to match the path in my live site, changed the index.html file generated in the dist folder to match the paths.

Console gives no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a file:/// url to watch the website? Vue should be served with a http server. If this is not the case please post some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using webpack (set up through vue-cli), you need to set the subfolder in the config and pass it to the troute.

- add `ROUTER_BASE` in the `config/****.env.js` file(s)
- set the base of the router to `ROUTER_BASE` (https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base)

`module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  ROUTER_BASE: '/subfolder'
}`

`new VueRouter({
  base: process.env.ROUTER_BASE,
  // ...etc
})`

Comment: This is a bit cleaner implementation that what I had been using. Nice.